# Standalone letters treated as words - regex, javascript

Tags: regex

I have this regex:  `/^[a-zA-Z'.,-]{5,500}$/`

But it doesn't treat standalone letters such as `a` or `I` as a whole word. I was wondering how to change it so letters are treated as words and numbers are ignored.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Change it to the following:

```
var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z'.,-]{1,500}$/;
                             ↑
```

Comment: It hasn't changed the output, I think this {1,500} only limits the allowed input

Comment: I have this code :  var side = document.getElementById("areaSquare").value.split(" ");
        var pattern = /\b[a-zA-Z'.,-]{1,500}\b/gi;

        for(var i = 0; i < side.length; i++)
        if(side[i] === " " && !side[i].match(pattern))  {
            alert("please fill in the field");
        }else {
            side[i].match(pattern);
            arr.push(side[i]);
            some = arr.map(function(value) {
                return value.toLowerCase();
            }).join(" ");

Comment: but it still doesn't output single letters only words

Comment: can you show your input string.. and expected results?

Answer (score 0):

You should watch out for `^` and `$` when you need to match *words*. You need [*word boundaries*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html): `\b`.

```
/\b[a-z'.,-]{1,500}\b/gi
```

This will allow matching *whole words* inside a larger input string. Also, the limiting quantifier `{5,500}` actually prevents matching words shorter than 5 characters long. Let's put it as `{1,500}`, but I doubt there is a real normal *word* that long. :)

```js
var re = /\b[a-zA-Z'.,-]{1,500}\b/gi; 
var str = 'I have seen the film before.';
alert(str.match(re));
```